# How to format empty braces on same line (Eclipse formatter)

Tags: eclipse, format

Where are the formatting settings in Eclipse to format an empty constructor like this

```
public ThisIsAConstructor() {} //this is supposed to be on one line
```

instead of

```
public ThisIsAConstructor() {
} //this is supposed to be on one line
```

I set everything in tab 'Brace positions' --> Same line. I am using the Google style guide (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml) with some custom adaptions.

Edit: I had some whitespaces in between, which prevented the expected formatting. If I have code like

```
public ThisIsAConstructor() {

} //this is supposed to be on one line
```

I have to format twice (one for removing the empty line via tab 'Blank Lines' an one for putting braces on one line. Is there a way to do that in one step?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to keep empty braces on the same line for most Java constructs, but unfortunately not for class constructors, as far as I could make out. If you haven't discovered it yet, here is how you get there:

In the Eclipse preferences, go to `Java -> Code Style -> Formatter` and click on `Edit...`.
This should open a new window where you can edit your profile.
On the hand left side, go to `New Lines -> Keep braced code on one line`. Here you can find a couple of constructs. For each you can set a condition in which the braces should be on one line. Choose `If empty` respectively.